# Custom Post Type Not Showing Single.php

Tags: php, wordpress, post, wordpress-theming, blogs

Can't wrap my head around it why my blog isn't showing single.php or single.php page. So far I have tried different options where I register post_type and also tried to reset permalinks but no luck.

Code in my functions.php

```
<?php

function wpdocs_create_blog_taxonomies()
{

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x('Blog', 'taxonomy general name', 'textdomain'),
        'menu_name'                  => __('Blog Categories', 'textdomain'),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_admin_column'     => true,
        'show_in_rest'          => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        'query_var'             => true,
        'rewrite'               => array('slug' => 'blog'),
    );

    register_taxonomy('blog_categories', 'blog', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'wpdocs_create_blog_taxonomies', 0);

function create_posttype()
{
    register_post_type(
        'blog',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => ('blog')
            ),
            'hierarchical'          => true,
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'taxonomies' => array('blog_categories', 'blog'),
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        )
    );
}

add_action('init', 'create_posttype');
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an issue with repeating slug names. Can't have page with same slug name. In my case it was blog.